# C++ Вопрос по реализации UDP чата

Tags: c++, сеть, сокет, winsock

Нужно реализовать клиент-серверное приложение для обмена сообщениями между компьютерами (простой чат), используя при этом UDP пакеты и только их. Также нужно поверх UDP реализовать подобие TCP, в отправляемом пакете помимо сообщения клиента должна быть контрольная сумма (CRC16). Должен быть реализован метод создания и закрытия сессии, аналогично тому, как это сделано в TCP (можно упрощенный вариант).

Вопрос:
Реализовать подключение клиента к серверу собираюсь через трехэтапное рукопожатие.
После этого у меня путаница, я не совсем понимаю, что я должен делать дальше.

1. Должен ли я использовать для подключения новых клиентов 1 сокет на сервере, а после создавать для каждого клиента отдельный сокет, через который осуществлять прием пакетов от клиента и отправку ему же?
2. Как можно реализовать начало и закрытие сессии? Интересует скорее закрытие, так как логично, что начало сессии начинается при успешном подключении клиента, а вот закрытие? Как пользуясь только UDP пакетами проверить, что пользователь по ту сторону кабеля ещё подключен? Сервер должен отправлять ему какой-то запрос каждые N секунд и проверять ответит ли тот и если нет то отключать? Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: 1. Нет. Серверу достаточно одного сокета. Из recvmsg вы получите адрес клиента, по которому надо отправить ответ. Естественно, клиент (отдельная программа) тоже делает один сокет. 2. Я бы возложил поддержку соединения на клиента. Раз в N секунд он шлет сообщение серверу, на которое сервер должен ответить. Решение о разрыве (для клиента это падение сервера) каждый принимает сам.